# Use name in other element than div or span, but still possible to show img

Tags: html

```
<span name="tumme"><img ...
```

is not valid because "name" is not valid in "span".

But I need to use name="tumme" and I need to be able to use text and img inside the tag.

So what tag can I use together with "name" and on the same time follow w3c?

Comment: You are asking an X-Y question. http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=542341 Please rephrase your question to provide context.

Comment: Regarding the other question you linked to, you should deselect the "correct" answer you chose, because it is WRONG.

Comment: @Johan: it seems strange that you seem concerned about "span name" not validating (but otherwise working for your purpose) but on the other hand choose an obvious hack (you are NOT linking to anything and neither is your intention to set an anchor) as the accepted answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the <a> tag with no href attribute.

Comment: yes, it is possible but please tell us why you need to do this.

Comment: Given the context of the OP's earlier questions, this would be a hack. The use is the name attribute is for scripting not linking. A class is the right way to go here.

Answer (score 9):

To answer the question directly, as per [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/index/attributes.html) the `name` attribute is allowed on the following HTML elements (very few of these will be useful to you):

- BUTTON
- TEXTAREA
- SELECT
- FORM
- FRAME
- IFRAME
- IMG
- A
- INPUT
- OBJECT
- MAP
- PARAM
- META

Answer (score 4):

Is there a reason you must use a "name" attribute rather than a class or an id?  Since both class and id are valid for span elements, and since span appears to be the most appropriate element to use,I'd set one of those to "tumme" rather than bending another element into shape.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1159361/update-two-same-value-in-html-with-one-ajax-response is the reason

Comment: please add that information to your question - so I could properly upvote David's answer... ;)

Comment: You still don't need to use a "name" attribute. Give each span a unique id so you can tell them apart if you want to, and give each span the class "tumme" so you can affect their behaviour as you wish. Use the javascript suggested in the other thread to pull all the elements with class="tumme", or use the id to pull the element and then check if it's class="tumme"

Answer (score 1):

As I said in response to your earlier question — [use classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1159361/update-two-same-value-in-html-with-one-ajax-response/1159456#1159456).

Comment: using classes is hard, lets go shopping!

Comment: this is very probably the correct answer when you know what the question really should have been but without knowing about the context of the question (i.e. the previous questions by this poster) this answer has no significance... :-P

Comment: A lot of code? It is one call to a pre-written function, and a loop over its results.

Comment: @Oliver - Well, since I LINKED to that question (or rather, my answer to that question) I think the significance is easy enough to find.

Comment: The joy of the X-Y problem (comment added to question)

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the only valid reason that I can think of where you would want to use the name attribute, is to have DOM access via document.getElementsByName()
or to use it as a FORM OUTPUT.

As a result, what you should be doing is using the HTML5 OUTPUT tag
and add the following in your HEAD tag for legacy browsers:

// Create a fake OUTPUT element, so IE can style it.

```
<script type="text/javascript> document.createElement("output");</script>
```

// Implement default style, so that it acts like a SPAN in other browsers:

```
<style type="text/css"> output { display:inline; border:0; outline:0; margin:0;padding:0; } </style>
```

http://html5doctor.com/the-output-element/

```
<output name="tumme"><img src="..." /></output>
```

If it is only for styling purposes or simple DOM query purposes
then you should use this as proposed earlier:

```
<span class="tumme"><img src="..." /></span>
```

or

```
<span id="tumme"><img src="..." /></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

`name` is only valid in the `<a>` tag IIRC (and form elements as was pointed out by David in the comments) but I'm pretty sure that is not what you're after:

`<a name="whatever"></a>` would create an "anchor" on a page that could be linked to with `<a href="#whatever">Link text</a>`.

Why do you need to use the `name` attribute? Why couldn't you simply use `id` instead?

Comment: There are plenty of elements that allow the name attribute (every form control for instance). The a element is one of the few which have seen official support removed (albeit in XHTML 1.1)

Comment: it has? so, how do you create an anchor in XHTML then?

Comment: I try that occasionally but found that browser support for that concept is still flaky - it's probably been half a year or so since I last tried linking to an `id` though...

Comment: Since HTML 4.0 the preferred way to create a point that can be linked to in a document is to set an id attribute on any element (such as a div surrounding the section you are linking to, or a heading at the start of it)

Comment: The last major browser that had issues linking to ids was Netscape 4

Comment: oh boy, looks like I need some more caffeine... I just found a section in our own code where I *did* link to `id`s just a couple of weeks ago... <blush/>

Comment: ...still wasn't aware that `<a name=` was deprecated. thanks for the hint.